# How to add links into my table with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

My code works good so far, but I want to make each table cell clickable where the real image opens by clicking on it. 
How do I do that?

```
echo "<table>";
$res = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = $mysqli->query($res);
    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
    {   
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";?> <img src=" <?php echo $myRow["image"];  ?>" height="100"    width="100"><?php echo "</td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>"
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? I mean, considering that the img properly fills the td, why not just wrap the img in a link?

Comment: I want to make it dynamic. Where it gets information from database and opens up only clicked image in real size. And there will be added new images to database all the time.

Comment: Doesn't prevent you from using a simple <a> tag to achieve this,

Comment: A simple a tag only opens defined image. I want it to define by itself what to open.

Comment: What.. Define itself? Nothing does anything by itself, you'll have to code it to do what you want it to.

Comment: This is what I want to do actually. First I want to get the array value of the image. And then use the same value for opening the image in a new php page.

Comment: http://localhost/test/webshop/webshop/display_images.php<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Image in <b>D:\xampp windows 8\htdocs\test\webshop\webshop\display_images.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner :) But it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the small image in `<a>` tags

```
<a href="http://path_to_images/<?=$myRow["image"]?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $myRow["image"];  ?>" height="100" width="100">
</a>
```

Comment: <a href="pictures/<?=$myRow["Image"]?>     This should work i guess. But it doesnt. I am working on localhost.

Comment: http://localhost/test/webshop/webshop/display_images.php<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Image in <b>D:\xampp windows 8\htdocs\test\webshop\webshop\display_images.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />

Comment: Sorry, thought it was a capital i in image. Edited.

Comment: Ohhhh! Thank you so much! Sorry I am a beginner :) But it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td>";?>
  "<a href=" <?=$myRow["image"];  ?>">
         <img src=" <?php echo $myRow["image"];  ?>" height="100" width="100" \>"<?php echo "
  <a/>
</td>";
```

Just put `<a href=""><a>` outside the img?

Comment: Yes but I want that <a> tag to automatically know which picture I clicked.

Comment: http://localhost/test/webshop/webshop/display_images.php<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Image in <b>D:\xampp windows 8\htdocs\test\webshop\webshop\display_images.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />

Comment: I dont really know what are you trying to do. Nothing happens automatically. You have to code it.